# JQuery with Mootools how to work togather?

Tags: jquery, mootools

I have a website that depends on JQuery and JavaScript in most of it. I found a login form in MooTools and I want to implement it but it seems there is a problem with that.
my header page is like following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="tr" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xml; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <!--Site CSS-->
    <link href="include-css/SCOREMIX.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Latest Jquery Lib-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <!-- Mootools - the core -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/mootools-core-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <!-- MooSlide (show/hide login form) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/mooSlide2-moo12.js"></script>
    <!--News scroller-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/jscroller-0.4.js"></script>

    <!--timer for ticking at live games and to update information each minute-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/jquery_timer.js" ></script>
    <!-- MY JS FILES-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/functions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/script.js" ></script>


    <script language="javascript" type="text/ecmascript">
    // Now you can use $ safely in this closure
    window.addEvent('domready',function(){
    var myLogin = new mooSlide2({ slideSpeed: 1500, fadeSpeed: 500,  toggler:'login', content:'loginPanel', close: false, effects:Fx.Transitions.Bounce.easeOut , from:'top'});
    //optional: AutoStart the slider on page load:
    //MyLogin.run();
    document.id('close').addEvent('click', function(e){
        e = new Event(e);
        myLogin.clearit();
        e.stop();
    });
});
    </script>

</head>
```

The error message that I got is in some line in the mooSlide2-moo12.js file :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setStyle'
```

How to solve this problem I use a 1.4.5 v of MooTools which does not have a doller sign problem because it uses a document.id instead.
can anybody give my a clue ??

mooSlide2-moo12.js:

```
// -------------------------------------------------
// artViper's mooSlide 3.2.1 revamp for mooTools 1.2
// -------------------------------------------------
// if you make significant changes, extensiosn etc
// please drop us a copy at admin@artviper.net
// -------------------------------------------------
// more mootools based stuff can be found at:
// ------------- www.artviper.net ------------------

    var mooSlide2 = new Class({
        options:    {
                        slideSpeed: 500,
                        fadeSpeed:  500,
                        effects:    Fx.Transitions.linear,
                        toggler:    "myToggle",
                        contentID:   null,
                        removeOnClick: true,
                        from:       'top',
                        opacity:    1,
                        height:     0,
                        isOpen:     0,
                        executeFunction: null,
                        loadExternal: null,
                        request: null
                    },

        initialize: function(options){
            this.setOptions(options);
            if(options['toggler']) this.toggler = options['toggler'];
            if(options['content']) this.content = $(options['content']);
            if(options['height']) this.height = options['height'];
            if(options['opacity']) this.opacity = options['opacity'];
            if(options['slideSpeed']) this.slideSpeed = options['slideSpeed'];
            if(options['fadeSpeed']) this.fadeSpeed = options['fadeSpeed'];
            if(options['close']) this.close = options['close'];
            if(options['from']) this.from = options['from'];
            if(options['executeFunction']) this.executeFunction = options['executeFunction'];
            if(options['loadExternal']) this.loadExternal = options['loadExternal'];

            if(this.close){
            $(this.content).addEvent('click',this.clearit.bindWithEvent(this));
            }

            if(options['effects']){
                this.effects = options['effects'];
            }else{
                this.effects = Fx.Transitions.linear;
            }
            this.content.setStyle('opacity','1');
            this.content.setStyle('visibility','hidden');
            this.content.setStyle('display','none'); // hide panel on page load
            $(this.content).setStyle('z-index','5000');
            $(this.toggler).addEvent('click',this.toggle.bindWithEvent(this));

        },

        clearit: function(){

            var myEffects = new Fx.Morph(this.content, {duration: this.fadeSpeed, transition: Fx.Transitions.linear});
            myEffects.start({
                 'opacity': [1, 0]
            });;
                    this.isOpen = 0;
                    var p = new Function(this.executeFunction);
                    p();

        },

        toggle: function(e){
            e = new Event(e).stop();
            var top =  window.getHeight().toInt() + window.getScrollTop().toInt();

            if(!this.isOpen){

                $(this.content).setStyle('position','absolute');
                $(this.content).setStyle('top',top);
                $(this.content).setStyle('height',this.height);
                $(this.content).setStyle('visibility','visible');
                $(this.content).setStyle('display','block');
                $(this.content).setStyle('opacity','1');
                $(this.content).setStyle('left','25%');

                var end;
                if(this.from == "top"){

                var myEffect = new Fx.Morph(this.content, {duration: this.slideSpeed, transition: this.effects});
                var totalEnd = end+this.height;

                myEffect.start({
                 'top': ['-200', '100']
                });

                    this.isOpen = 1;
                }

            }else{
            var myEffects = new Fx.Morph(this.content, {duration: this.fadeSpeed, transition: Fx.Transitions.linear});
            myEffects.start({
                 'opacity': [1, 0]
            });

                this.isOpen = 0;
                var p = new Function(this.executeFunction);
                p();
            }
        }
    })

mooSlide2.implement(new Options);
mooSlide2.implement(new Events);
```

Comment: You should really try and find a similar implementation of that login form for jQuery instead. Makes no sense at all to include MooTools only for that.

Comment: Also, why use XHTML? It's archaic and outdated. Just go with `<!DOCTYPE html>` and you're good to go ;)

Comment: I can not my boss wants this one and he is stubborn :) . and I did not fine something similar to it.

Comment: Well you should explain to him why it's bad, and maybe that will change his mind. There's a reason you do this job and not him.

Comment: What function do you have in jQuery? Maybe there is also the same in Mootools so you can take away the jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

```
// Now you can use $ safely in this closure
```

There is no closure here ^^

MooSlide uses the `$`function. If MooTools does not overwrite the `$` function of jQuery then MooSlide won't work. On possible solution is to actually use a closure:

```
(function($){
   // Now you can use $ safely in this closure
   window.addEvent('domready',function(){
   var myLogin = new mooSlide2({ ...

})(document.id)
```

Comment: before the click. and the jQuery.noconflict does not work also . do I miss something I will go crazy man

Comment: You wrote that you use MooTools 1.4.5 but your code has `mootools12.js`.

Comment: you are right it is copy/paste problem because I was using mootools12.js and then upgrade to mootools1.4.5 to overcome dollar sign problem and start using document.id

Comment: If you use a current version then it's almost impossible that the closure does not solve the problem. Could you update your code with the closure, try it out and post it?

Comment: I edit my post and add the script of mootools the error is in the 49 line this.content.setStyle('opacity','1');